# Why can't I use the terraform totem in Reprisal?

Tags: reprisal

In [Reprisal](http://www.reprisaluniverse.com), I like to quickly clean up my newly conquered islands with the terraform totem.

Unfortunately, when I tried to exert my will on the landscape in a recent game, I found I was flatly denied.

You can see the crossed out cursor totem here:

[image: totem denied]

I know that a certain amount of mana is necessary to use the totem, but the screenshot also shows that I definitely had enough mana for any terraform actions.

### What is preventing me from using the terraform totem?

Comment: I know that you can't terraform close to opponent towns, but that doesn't appear to be the case here

Comment: The area in this screenshot was formerly controlled by others, but this was after I had completely removed them from the area.